# TFS Build reports not showing original branch's comments

Tags: tfs, msbuild

We have a "Main" branch and a "Dev" branch in source control; pretty common approach where developers work off of the Dev branch and merge changes to Main at set periods when the code has been unit tested and is ready for customer testing.

We link Work Items like PBI's (Scrum) and require comments on checkins. Normally the TFS build report will show the attached work items and changesets.  Our dev build (Dev branch) does indeed do this.

But, our Main build which uses merged changesets from the Dev branch doesn't "inherit" those links.  If you read our Main build (Main branch) report it shows none of the original changesets; just the "Merged from Dev" one.

Does anyone know if it is possible to make TFS look though the branches for all of the changes from the merges and put those in the build report?

Comment: Can you confirm the version of TFS you are using?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is only available in 2010 I believe.